# How to detect which command button is clicked?

Tags: commandbutton

I have 2 command buttons on my vf page:

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="saveAndnewmethod()" value="Save and New"/>
<apex:commandButton onclick="savemethod()" value="Save"/>
```

and they call different js method. but these js methods have a lot of common lines of codes that I want to merge it into just one method.

```
function save(){
  //...common lines
  if(someValidations == true){
  $('.savebtn').prop('disabled', true);
  save_ACC_Cont();//this is an action function of button save
  }
}
function saveAndnewmethod(){
//...common lines
  if(someValidations == true){
    save_and_new();////this is an action function of button save and new
    $('.savebtn').prop('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

what i would want to do is merge the function and detect which button is clicked so that i would only call one js method and avoid repetitive lines. how will i do it? hope someone could help...

Comment: you can pass a paramter to the method to find which button has clicked

Comment: or you can use event to identify the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the parameter in the Javascript function and then check the value for both the case. For example Pass **Save** from the save button and pass **SaveAndNew** from save and new button.

Below will be the code for command button

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="commonFunction('SaveAndNew')" value="Save and New"/>
<apex:commandButton onclick="commonFunction('Save')" value="Save"/>
```

And below will be the javascript code

```
function commonFunction(buttonClicked){
    //.. Common Lines
    if(buttonClicked === 'SaveAndNew'){
        //.. save and new logic here
    }else if(buttonClicked === 'Save'){
        //... logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way use event to identify the button

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="commonFunction(event)" value="Save and New"/>
<input type="button" id="btn2" onclick="commonFunction(event)" value="Save"/>
```

And in javascript use  `e.target.id`

```
function commonFunction(e){
    //.. Common Lines
    if(e.target.id === 'btn1'){
        //.. save and new logic here
    }else if(e.target.id === 'btn2'){
        //... logic here
    }
}
```

Just remember if you use apex button it will have the form page pageblock etc ids as well